# Selenium Python driver.find.elements get attribute

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
def n_seguidores(self, username):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+ username +'/')
    time.sleep(3)
    user_botao = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('g47SY ')
    print_us = user_botao.get_attribute('title')
    print(print_us)
```

please help me to find numbers of following from html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, could you explain yourself on this question? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

`.find_elements_*` return a list, so you need access by index.

There are 3 numbers with the same class name in the page, and the **`numbers of following`** you mean is the third.

And to get the number you can use `.text`, not `.get_attribute('title')`

Try following code:

```
user_botao = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('g47SY ')
#second index
print_us = user_botao[2].text
print(print_us)
```